# Present simple followed by present continious

Tags: present-continuous, present-simple

I am trying to understand, why answers are that. I am talking about the second sentence.

As answers I did put in - "is really killing me, are bleeding, am still wanting"

But correct is the only one in the middle. And first is - "really kill" and last - "still want"

This makes no sense to me because the task is about present simple and present continuous. Repeated action explanation here doesn't work either, because in the middle there's another tense, not present simple. And actions are happening in the time of the speech, so... Yeah. It confuses me :D Bellow is the text of a task. Thanks :)

> Today (be) .............. the second day of my trek around Mount Annapurna. I am exhausted and my legs (shake) ............; I just hope I am able to complete the trek. My feet
>   (kill, really)............. me and my toes (bleed) .........., but I (want, still).......... to continue.
>   Nepal is a fascinating country, but I have a great deal to learn

Comment: Welcome! I guess it is nicer to show the effort you'd already made. For example, when I am not sure the usage of a word, I usually look up the definition/explanation and examples [on a dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/) or other trusted reference. And then I might ask some question based on that. That would help answerers know what you've understood and what not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of the three gaps, there is a clear answer for the last one.  The verb "want" gives a current state. It is rare to use "am wanting", this verb is nearly always in simple present.  So it must be "I still want to continue."

The first two could be either simple present or present continuous (with a slight change in meaning,  I would prefer present continuous in both cases.

In the first the verb "kill" is not being used in the main sense of "cause the death", but in a metaphorical way, meaning "hurt".  If the author had said "My feet really hurt".  That would be correct, but it is not common to use "kill" in the simple present in this sense.

Your mistake is because you have two feet.  So "My feet **are** really killing me".